# No module named pip on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm running macOS 11.2.2 Big Sur and I'm trying to get pip to work with the latest Python 3.9.4. This turned out to be ridiculously difficult even though I've read a number of articles on the subject. Possibly, it is the debris I accumulated in the system over the years which is causing me trouble. I need advice as to how to get things right again.

Checklist:

- `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3 --version` is Python 3.9.4 installed from `brew` in the most usual way; it's a symlink to `../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`, which is in `Cellar`.
- Both `python` and `python3` commands are aliased to `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3`, they give the correct version.
- I used both [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and [ensurepip](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#ensurepip), and both of them say everything is fine: "Successfully installed pip-21.1.1 setuptools-56.0.0"
- The only thing in `env` that has anything to do with Python is this part of PATH: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin`. The lack of this one is reported as warning when you install pip.

Still, I get this:

```
python -m pip --version
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named pip
```

What am I missing?

I also found [this article](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) that instructs to use `pyenv`, but running it on the latest macOS is yet another problem: `pyenv install 3.9.4` doesn't build for some reason.

Comment: you ran `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`?

Comment: Yep, it says everything's fine: `Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip`
`Successfully installed pip-21.1.1 setuptools-56.0.0`. When I attempt to run pip, it says `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip", line 5, in <module> from pip._internal.cli.main import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'"`

Comment: and when you ran `get-pip` did you do it this way? `python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/` and please show what your `PATH` variable looks like as well

Comment: @gold_cy Thank you so much, this worked! Why don't they say this on the pip website?! I've lost more than two hours trying to get this working. :(

Comment: they do, it's on this page --> https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line

Comment: I meant the pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing page. Anyway, this was a surprising hitch. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pointers from `@gold_cy` in the comments I was able to resolve the problem by running `get-pip.py` with an additional parameter: `--prefix=/usr/local/`.

While the official [pip installation guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) does mention that there may be problems on the systems like macOS that manage their own Python install, it doesn't say directly what you can do about it. Which is a shame, because the phrasing in [PyPA » Python Packaging User Guide » Tutorials » Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line) is exactly the same, only the last phrase is missing from pip's page:

> **Warning** Be cautious if you’re using a Python install that’s managed by your
> operating system or another package manager. `get-pip.py` does not coordinate
> with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state. You can
> use python `get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/` to install in `/usr/local` which is
> designed for locally-installed software.

Comment: I really don't think this is a good idea. The proper solution is to figure out what's wrong in your Python's `sys.path`, and solve that. Overriding whatever `brew` already installed is only likely to drive you further down into a situation where you can't control which Python libraries are actually being used for what.

Comment: Half a year later it proved to be working just fine for me. ‍♂️

Comment: Sure, if you're lucky, you can just disregard the warning; but it's not a solution I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to resolve the problem for `python3` in MacOS. The accepted answer didn't help me.

What helped me is complete reinstall of the python3:

```
brew uninstall python3  # if python3 worked before
brew install python3
```